# "onrendered" in html2canvas not being called

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas

I am using jsPdf to generate pdf from HTML Div. as from_html was not working I am using html2canvas function to create pdf which will convert html into base64 image and that will be added to canvas. I don't see any error in console, but the code in onrendered event is not being executed. That means onrendered is not being called. I could not find what is wrong. I searched a lot but no beneficial results.

Now I have added one option for html2canvas function as "logging" : "true", then I see there is a log "95534ms html2canvas: Document cloned" and after that I have 404 (Invalid SID) Post error.

below is my code snippet :

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p','pt','letter');
     widget.log('doc : '+doc+' jspdf : '+ new jsPDF());
     html2canvas( [divDocEdit], {
        'logging' : 'true',
        onrendered: function( canvas ) {
            alert("in onrendered");
            console.log("Canvas : "+canvas+" divDocedit : "+divDocEdit);
            var imgData = canvas.toDataURL();              
            //var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
            doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
            doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
    }
    });
```

In above code divDocEdit is the "[object HTMLDivElement]".
Any feedback/suggestion is appreciated. looking forward for your valuable comments.
Thanks